# How to get the checked radio button in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have seen that this works for most of users, but for some reason it doesn't for me. I use Google Chrome.

```
radioBut = document.querySelector(".rad-design")
getColor = function(){
for (i=0; i<radioBut.length; i++){
    if (radioBut[i].checked){
        console.log(radioBut[i)   
    }
}
```

Html

```
                <form id = "rad">
                    <div class = "radioAll">
                        <label class="rad-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="rad-input"  name="colList">
                            <div class="rad-design"></div>
                        </label>
                        <label class="rad-label">
                            <input type="radio" class="rad-input"  name="colList">
                            <div class="rad-design"></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>       
                  </form>
```

Comment: maybe you should replace `check` to `checked` in your input : `<input type="radio" class="rad-input" checked name="colList">`

Comment: my bad, it's a wrong code snippet, i don't have that part in the project

Comment: and that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector should be `document.querySelectorAll` to get inputs as array and you should target to `.rad-input` class which is the input and not `.rad-design` which is the label. Also you should use `checked` for the inputs to make the input checked, its not `check`. Also you cannot set `checked` to two inputs with same name. If thats done only the last input with that name will be checked.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const radioBut = document.querySelectorAll(".rad-input")
getColor = function () {
    for (i = 0; i < radioBut.length; i++) {
        if (radioBut[i].checked) {
            console.log(radioBut[i])
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="rad">
    <div class="radioAll">
        <label class="rad-label">
            <input type="radio" class="rad-input" checked name="colList">
            <div class="rad-design">One</div>
        </label>
        <label class="rad-label">
            <input type="radio" class="rad-input" name="colList">
            <div class="rad-design">Two</div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="getColor()">getColor</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns just one element not an array/list, so in the for loop at `i<radioBut.length` radioBut.length is `undefined`, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead.

Also I noticed you have selected the div and not the input and you have a couple of syntax errors.

Maybe this can help you:

```js
const radioBut = document.querySelectorAll(".rad-input")
const getColor = function(){
  for (let i=0; i<radioBut.length; i++){
      if (radioBut[i].checked){
          console.log(radioBut[i].value)   
      }
  }
}

console.log(getColor())
```

```html
<form id = "rad">
    <div class = "radioAll">
        <label class="rad-label">
            <input type="radio" class="rad-input"  value='A' name="colList">
            <div class="rad-design"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="rad-label">
            <input type="radio" class="rad-input"  value='B' name="colList" checked>
            <div class="rad-design"></div>
        </label>
    </div>       
  </form>
```

Another options is to use the `form` element functionality

```js
const form = document.getElementById('rad');

const getColor = function(){
   return form.colList.value;
}

console.log(getColor())
```

```html
<form id = "rad">
    <div class = "radioAll">
        <label class="rad-label">
            <input type="radio" class="rad-input"  value='A' name="colList">
            <div class="rad-design"></div>
        </label>
        <label class="rad-label">
            <input type="radio" class="rad-input"  value='B' name="colList" checked>
            <div class="rad-design"></div>
        </label>
    </div>       
  </form>
```